# how to get the filter value of current selected value rather than previous selected value in laravel filament?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

i am trying to get the filter value inside getTableQuery(): Builder, which is inside a widget and extends TableWidget .but i am not getting expected selected value from filter .

i have put getTableQuery(): Builder, which is inside a widget and extends TableWidget .
so i am trying to fetch the filter value by using             $this->tableFilters['month']['value']
then initially i am getting null instead of default date .

then if i am selecting any other month then i am getting value of previous selected one .

how to fix the issue and get the filter value of current selected value rather than previous selected value ??